# R error: ' Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).'

Tags: r, regression

I'm getting this error :

> Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).

Here is my code

```
ge19 <- read.csv("ge2019.csv")
aps19 <- read.csv("aps19.csv")

ge19aps19 <- merge(ge19, aps19,by="ons_id")

ge19aps19$london <- ge19aps19$region_name

table(ge19aps19$london)

library (dplyr)
library(forcats)

ge19aps19$london <- fct_drop(ge19aps19$london)
table(ge19aps19$london)

ge19aps19$london <- relevel(ge19aps19$london, ref= "London")

table(ge19aps19$london)

ge19aps19$lab.per <- ge19aps19$lab/ge19aps19$valid_votes
ge19aps19$lab.per <- fct_drop(ge19aps19$lab.per)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? first time user of this site so please let me know if there's more information needed / I've formatted my question wrong

Comment: Yes, you had [formated your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) wrong, why all those quotes?

Comment: oh, i thought that was how you made it into code, let me edit and try again

Comment: Don't edit, it's already done.

Comment: oh @RuiBarradas you formatted again for me, thanks so much, any idea how to fix my error?

Comment: The line before the last computes a ratio, a continuous result, and in the last one you drop the factor levels of that ratio. There are no levels to drop since it's not a factor, hence the error.

Comment: so i probably don't need to drop the levels after?

Comment: As for the quotes, they would be backticks before and after each code line but even better is 3 backticks before and after the code block.

Comment: No, don't drop the levels.

Comment: okay, thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message mean that the param you passed to `fct_drop` function is neighther `factor` or `character`.

And from the your code I saw that `ge19aps19$lab.per` is a `numeric` column calculated by this formula

```
ge19aps19$lab.per <- ge19aps19$lab/ge19aps19$valid_votes
```

Why you run `fct_drop` on that column? It is a numeric column so `fct_drop` threw an error message there!